# How to add new fields in redux-auth on signup page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using [redux-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth) to user authentication in my react-redux web application.

I am not getting how to add more fields on signup page. please find redux-auth [signup component here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth/blob/master/src/views/default/EmailSignUpForm.js)

Comment: I have found issues at [https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth/issues/84](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth/issues/84) but no one has response there

Comment: any update on it?